# Воспроизвести видео, вместо того, чтобы скачивать его

Tags: apache, веб-программирование

У меня на сервере есть папка с видео в формате (.MOV).

[image: files]

Когда я на них нажимаю, они начинают скачиватся. Я хочу, чтобы видео открывалось в браузере. Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Comment: [**Похоже, что нельзя**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23927710/5951529) без установленных аддонов на стороне клиента. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду что-то придумывать.

Comment: В Chrome достаточно как html5 video добавить: `<!doctype html><video src="IMG_1174.mov" autoplay></video>`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для этих файлов установить http-заголовок `Content-Disposition: inline`.

Более подробно можно почитать в посвящённом этому RFC: 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt